# man command not working

Tags: manpage

My `man` command seems to have disappeared.

Typing `man <something>` returns

```
The program 'man' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install man-db
```

however `man-db` is already installed and reinstalling it does nothing. Typing `which man` doesn't find anything.

xman works, so the actual man pages are there: it seems the front-end driver has gone missing. How can I download the front-end driver or recreate a copy of it (I seem to recall it's a small shell script).

Running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS on a Dell laptop with x86 processor

`/usr/bin/man` doesn't exist - that's essentially the problem.

I did try uninstalling `man-db` (as root) in order to reinstall it, but it won't let me. It gets a permission failure. I thought root could do anything, but apparently not....

Comment: Can you check the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/man`. It should have 755 permissions, owned by root.

Comment: What did you do before this issue?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual commands you are using to try to reinstall / uninstall the package - and the complete error messages

Answer (score 1):

Well, the (rather horrible) workaround was to download the Ubuntu 14.04 install image, create an install DVD, boot it up on another machine, copy /usr/bin/man across, chmod it to 755, and I have a working man command again. There ought to be an easier way to recreate a file which has somehow got corrupted or gone missing, such as forcing a reinstall of the package.

Comment: There is: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ...`